# Google Script - RegexExtract/RegexReplace multi-line content

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

CONTEXT

- Column with multi-line content from where I need to remove (replace) or extract data
  *original content e.g.*

> ● image001.png
> image002.png
> Payment Ref - Proc. 7304_18.6T8TIR.pdf
> https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/XXXXXXXXXXX
> ● image005.png
> image006.png
> Payment Ref - Proc. 25258_07.2T8TES.pdf.
> https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/YYYYYYYYY.

Content is not always with this order and the quantity of items may vary

WHAT I NEED

- Final Result should be also in one cell, like
  *e.g.*

> Payment Ref - Proc. 7304_18.6T8TIR.pdf
> Payment Ref - Proc. 25258_07.2T8TES.pdf

It can contain the bullet, not a problem, if it ends up in the beggining of each final result line

WHAT I HAVE SO FAR

- By using:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(F3:F,".(?s)image.*.(png)",""))`

- I get:

> Payment Ref - Proc. 7304_18.6T8TIR.pdf
> https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/XXXXXXXXXXX
> ●
> Payment Ref - Proc. 25258_07.2T8TES.pdf.
> https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/YYYYYYYYY.

- If I try to replace the "http..." on another column, based on the one I used the 1st regexreplace:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(G3:G,".(?s)http.*",""))`

- Nothing different happens
- If I use:

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(G3:G,"(?s).*Pay.*|pay.*"))`

- I get the same result as the first regexreplace, leaving the unwanted url

Is there a way to strip out all at once from one cell to another (remove lines that have "image" + URL addresses) - or at least with the least number of operations possible - or just extract all lines that contain "payment" in that cell, to another cell (per row and not from all rows to one cell), in google sheets?

Thanks in advance

[Test Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gRcXx2jFjyV9-kb-MmszzcLqjSZnNH5W_U1ikW5vYBs/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  - From

    ```
      ● image001.png
      image002.png
      Payment Ref - Proc. 7304_18.6T8TIR.pdf
      https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/XXXXXXXXXXX
      ● image005.png
      image006.png
      Payment Ref - Proc. 25258_07.2T8TES.pdf.
      https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/YYYYYYYYY.
    ```
  - To

    ```
      Payment Ref - Proc. 7304_18.6T8TIR.pdf
      Payment Ref - Proc. 25258_07.2T8TES.pdf
    ```
- You want to put the result values in one cell.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, it supposes that each value from `● image###.png` to `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/XXXXXXXXXXX` is put in each cell.

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"(Payment Ref[\s\w].+\.pdf)"))))
```

#### Result:

[image]

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, it supposes that all values from `● image###.png` to `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/XXXXXXXXXXX` are put in one cell.

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(Payment Ref[\s\w].+\.pdf)","($1)")))))
```

#### Result:

[image]

### Note:

- At both sample formulas, each value `Payment Ref - Proc. 7304_18.6T8TIR.pdf` is retrieved using `REGEXEXTRACT`. And the values are put in one cell using `TEXTJOIN`.

### References:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)

### Added:

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(● | ● )?image[ \S\w]+\n|https.+\n?|\.\n","")))
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: very complete answer!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've created a test spreadsheet because I think a) I'm doing something wrong, b) I didn't explain myself properly, c) both! :) Pattern 2 seems to be working better but it's joining the payment ref from all rows and it should only show the values per row. Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gRcXx2jFjyV9-kb-MmszzcLqjSZnNH5W_U1ikW5vYBs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user1128912 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that I couldn't suppose the various values in your shared Spreadsheet. From your shared Spreadsheet, I proposed one more sample formula. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you once again for your effort and help. Indeed, that's it! My regex choice was poor and yours does the trick. Also, the trim is well thought. Thank you for the explanation